# Select list items and replace all their occurances with html formatting syntax

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a big text file that contains a list of items, such as:
a. item number one
b. item number two
c. item number three
d. ..
e. ..

Under that list there is an elaborating text that gives an idea about each item, such as:

At home we need item number one as it helps in cleaning. As for item number two, if you are a handy person you will certainly need it as it protects your hands. In regards to item number three, it is a must to have to protect your children from crawling insects. Etc.

What I am after is a find & replace expression for Notepad++ to select eg "item number one" only without "a. " (a dot space) from the list and replace it with html colour formatting syntax `<font color = "red">item number one</font>`, so the listed item will be distinguishable in red when the elaborating text is displayed in the browser. Thus, the previous paragraph will be like the following before it is pasted on the website:

At home we need `<font color = "red">item number one</font>` as it helps in cleaning. As for `<font color = "red">item number two</font>`, if you are a handy person you will certainly need it as it protects your hands. In regards to `<font color = "red">item number three</font>`, it is a must to have to protect your children from crawling insects. Etc.

Can anyone help with this please?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

Find what: `(item number \w+)`
Replace with: `<font color = "red">$1</font>`

According to your comment, here is a way to select what you want in your list of items:

Find what: `(?<=^\w\. ).+$`

Comment: Thanks very much M42 for your promptness. In fact "item number one" and so other items, are different variable strings. eg "rubber gloves with sizes S,M,L" instead of "item number one" and "odorless insect surface spray" instead of "item number two" etc. Can "Find What:" statement be modified to select the exact item name?

Comment: @JosefMiller: OK, I see. I'm afraid this isn't a job for regex in npp, you have to write a script.

Comment: with this expression `([a-z]{1}[.].*)` I can select the entire item line. Is there any way that enables me to exclude the first three characters eg "a. " (a dot space)?